# Intel HD4000 HDMI and Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, intel-graphics, hdmi, integrated

Any ideas what can I do in order to get HDMI output in Ubuntu 13.04? I have an integrated Intel Hd4000 card.

It is very frustrating that this basic function still doesn't work..

This is the output of xrandr:

```
530U3C-530U4C:~$ xrandr
```

Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1366 x 768, maximum 32767 x 32767
LVDS1 connected 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1366x768       60.1*+
   1360x768       59.8     60.0
   1024x768       60.0
   800x600        60.3     56.2
   640x480        59.9
VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)

HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)

DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)

Comment: is this your only graphic card ? Or do have a dedicated graphic chip ? What laptop/desktop model are we speaking of?

Comment: Yes, the intel HD4000 is my only graphic card. The laptop model is Samsung Series 5 Ultra 530U3C

Answer (score 0):

If the driver is installed and is ok, it is just to do

$ xrandr --output HDMI1

Note that HDMI1 may be a different name for your system. To enable sound, install pavucontrol

$ sudo apt-get install pavucontrol

and choose the appropriate output in the 'Configuration' tab.

Comment: Nothing happens when I do this. No error or something. In Windows it is ok, so it isn't a TV problem

Answer (score 0):

I'm probably resurrecting an old issue, but I had the same issue with my XPS 14 Ultrabook.

It turns out that my laptop would display to a monitor via HDMI just fine, but not my TV.  Disabling the overscan function on my TV resolved this, although I'm not sure why.

When you output to this display in windows is it 'technically' in 1080 but the top/bottom of the screen is slightly clipped off?

If so you may look into disabling the overscan function on your TV or setting it to a PC mode if it has it available (My Emerson TV just had a PC mode to set).

Also, try plugging into just a regular HDMI monitor to check if your HDMI port has some functionality